# how to get data from database and display it in the form in order to update the content

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

i have an update function that allow user to  update the inserted record using django. i tried to filter the object based on the id. then once i return the id i  assume i am able to  get all fields.

the problem is that when i go to update page the form is empty and no data are return.

## views.py

```
def update(request,pk):
    #deny anonymouse user to enter the  create page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login")
    else:
        dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk =pk)
        print( "db entry : ",dbEntry)

        return render(request,'blog/update.html', {"dbEntry":dbEntry})
```

## update.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/linesAnimation.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/input-lineBorderBlue.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/dropDown.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/home.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/meta-Input.css' %}">
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'%}"></script>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="lines">
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  </div>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id='left-column-Input' class="formInput" include="select()"> 
        <div class="forminputs">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autocomplete="off" required />
        <label for="fname" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name" name="fname">{{dbEntry.suspect_name}}</span>
        </label></div>
<div class="home-Button">
    <button id="save" name="save" type="submit">Edit</button>
    <button id="clear" name="clear" type="submit">Clear</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what happens if you try `dbEntry = suspect.objects.get(pk=pk)` instead of `dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk =pk)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django, `filter` returns QuerySet of elements that are matched to your filter. In your case, you used `filter` and therefore your `dbEntry` is a QuerySet. But if you do that you need to use a `for` loop in your template in order to access the object fields. In your case you need to use `get`, which returns a single object. You can find more detail from the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

So Just change:

```py
dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk=pk)
```

to

```py
dbEntry = suspect.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

When using `get` you need to be careful about the exceptions. Your `get` call will throw `DoesNotExist` if no objects are found.. Similarly, if your `get` query will throw `MultipleObjectsReturn` exception when more than 1 element is found.

**When to use filter and when to use get?**

There no strict answer to this question. When you want to get an element by its unique field, for example the primary key, you can use `get` because you are sure you will get at most one object or no objects (if does not exist).

If you want to get a list of objects (students who are named "Joe" etc.) you need to use `filter`. That will return a QuerySet and you can show the elements of that list by iterating that QuerySet by using a for loop in your django template such as:

```html
{% for obj in your_objects %}
    <tr><td>{{ obj.name }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: so now i am able to get all fields related to the selected record ? and be able to update the data right?

Comment: Yes, by using```get``` you will only have the record with that ```pk``` and all of it's fields.

Comment: so wen to use get ? and when to use filter ?